# How to append cell (String) value from Excel file to JTextArea?

Tags: java, excel, jtextarea

this is my problem:

I try to append value from cell's in loop from Excel file. I use this part of code:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for(Iterator<Row> rit = sheet.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();)
            {
                Row row = rit.next();

                for(Iterator<Cell> cit = row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();)
                {
                    Cell cell = cit.next();


                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

                    while(cit.hasNext())
                    {
                        notatnik.append(String.valueOf(cell.getSheet().toString()) + "\n");
                    }

                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");         
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

But it's only got back value "1" or "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet@6325a3ee". In the excel I have for example value:
1     SP25      kp      5      6.5 etc.

What should I do, to get back this value from Excel to JTextArea?

PS. I use POI 3.10 library.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a little mess with the iterator ...

The iterator should be used this way:

```
Iterator<Cell> cit = row.cellIterator(); // you get the iterator ...

while (cit.hasNext()) {
  // let't go cell by cell
  Cell cell = cit.next();
  System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
}
```

Not sure why are you printing out the `cell.getSheet()` as this value is always the same (you are on the same sheet) ... probably you are looking for `cell.getValue()` ... or something similar

Comment: Thanks, I try it.

Noo I use "System.print.put(...)" only for check if this method work :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for answer (and will have the same problem as me) this is a part of code from my program:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            try
            {
                Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                for(Iterator<Row> rit = sheet.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();)
                {
                    Row row = rit.next();

                    for(Iterator<Cell> cit = row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();)
                    {
                        Cell cell = cit.next();

                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        notatnik.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    }
                    notatnik.append("\n");
                }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This part of the code gets all the values ​​from the excel file and pastes them to JTextArea about called "notatnik".